# "using" block together with "dynamic"

Tags: c#, dynamic, using

If I write

```
using (dynamic d = getSomeD ()) {
   // ...
}
```

does that mean that `d.Dispose ()` is called when the `using` block is left?

What happens when `d` does not implement `IDisposable`?

Comment: RuntimeBinderException is what happens. http://i.imgur.com/DOleSwh.png

Comment: Was there any reason you couldn't answer both of these questions yourself by trying it?

Comment: [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) or [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) are great for trying out behaviors like this. Here's my attempt at this on .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/E7kk1Z

Comment: @Jon: Yes, the result of trying is less reliable than the answer of somebody who *knows* it. In particular when dealing with dynamic.

Comment: In order to show research, you should (IMO) at least have tried them for yourself - then documented the results, and asked for confirmation that this was guaranteed/specified behaviour, IMO.

Comment: Hm, yes, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does that mean that d.Dispose () is called when the using block is
>   left?

Yes. If the type implements `IDisposable` then  `Dispose` will be called.

> What happens when d does not implement IDisposable?

You will get an exception

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll
>   Cannot implicitly convert type 'YourType' to 'System.IDisposable'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

You can try that yourself by having a class like:

```
class MyDisposable : IDisposable //Remove IDisposable to see the exception
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose called");
    }
}
```

and then:

```
using (dynamic d = new MyDisposable())
{

}
```

Comment: If anyone is curious as to what happens under the hood with the dynamic, [**this**](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6b0334c7a7e86528d09d) code compiles to [**this**](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e6a2895643b5597968a6) (in LINQPad targeting .NET 4). Here's what the IL looks like: [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ebd3a464edae7bce809b)

Comment: also to add, `using` will translate into `try/finally` block.